# Inserting Data From C# Form Into Linked Database?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm building an application using C# and have decided to go with a windows Form. The goal is to have a user register and be able to login with their login credentials they set up in the registration form.

Registration Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string connetionString = null;
     connetionString = @"Data Source=THANATOS\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=LoginDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

     SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Connection = cnn;

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", first_NameTextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", last_NameTextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", usernameTextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordTextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", email_AddressTextBox.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNumbers", passwordTextBox.Text);

     cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO UserRegiatration VALUES @FirstName, @LastName, @Username, @Password, @EmailAddress, @PhoneNumbers)");

     try
     {
         cnn.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         MessageBox.Show("You Have Been Registered!");
         cnn.Close();
     }
     catch (System.Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please Try Again At A Later Time.");
     }
}
```

This is what I have so far but I can't get the information the user enters in the text boxes to post to the database upon the button click event happening.

Any idea what I need to include or remove to improve this?

Comment: Does an exception happen (do you get the "Try again" messagebox)?

Comment: How exactly is this failing?  When you debug, what *specifically* happens?

Comment: When I debug it throws System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
Incorrect syntax near '@FirstName'.'

Comment: you are missing a brace `(` in your insert statement

Comment: what are the fields in schema  (fields) for your table UserRegiatration ?

Comment: @PhoneNumbers = password.text???

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `(`:

```
INSERT into UserRegiatration VALUES 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Username,@Password,@EmailAddress,@PhoneNumbers)
^
```

Also, did you mean to write `UserRegistration` or is the table really called `UserRegiatration`?

Comment: the table is actually called UserRegistration, when I debug the program it throws System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
Incorrect syntax near '@FirstName'.'

Comment: And does it still throw that exception after you've fixed these two typos?

Comment: this is what i currently have entered.   cmd.CommandText = "(INSERT into UserRegiatration VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@Username,@Password,@EmailAddress,@PhoneNumbers)";

Comment: Try `cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into UserRegistration VALUES(@FirstName,@LastName,@Username,@Password,@EmailAddress,@PhoneNumbers)";`.

Comment: So when I use that, and i run it, it breaks out @  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName".'

Comment: Did you by any chance skip the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", first_NameTextBox.Text);` that time?

Comment: I made the changes and began to run it, it breaks out at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Ive pushed these latest changes to Github. https://github.com/PcHelpPros/LoginForm.git

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you should have your table name should be surrounded in brackets.

It would look like:

```
INSERT into [UserRegiatration] VALUES 
(@FirstName,@LastName,@Username,@Password,@EmailAddress,@PhoneNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my tables and did some more research, it turns out, I was missing the part of the statement which identified which specific columns the information was supposed to be inserted into. This is what is now working for me. Thanks for the guidance and the troubleshooting advice.

```
private void registerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connetionString = null;
        connetionString = @"Data Source=THANATOS\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=LoginDatabase;Integrated Security=True";                       
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) // Checking connection status, if closed then open.
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.[Table] (FirstName,LastName,Username,Password,Email,PhoneNum) VALUES (@FirstName,@LastName,@Username,@Password,@Email,@PhoneNum)";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {                       

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastNameTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", usernameTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passwordTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNum", phoneNumTextBox.Text); // Syntax @"TableColumnName", TextBoxToGrabInfoFrom.Text

                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Check Error
                    if (result < 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Error inserting data into Database!"); // If error, display message.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string v = ex.Message;
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    private void phoneNumLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}